# How to set camera of android device as source type for javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, android-camera, ar.js

So, I am making an AR-application and have some basic code which runs fine on a pc-browser.

The piece of code that activates the webcam is the following:

```
        //handle arToolkitSource
        var arToolkitSource = new THREEx.ArToolkitSource({
            // to read from the webcam 
            sourceType : 'webcam',  
        })
```

When I use an android device I get the error:

Webcam Error
Name: NotFoundError
Message: The object cannot be found here.

I would however like this code to work on android browsers as well so do you think there is a solution for this problem?

The code I used as a template can be found in this link:

https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/examples/basic.html

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?